# Reset timer each access

Tags: php

I'm developing a program that runs on the server and tracks the access of a local program.

Each time this program locally accesses the URI, the program is in the server that is running need to starts the script again. If the program does not access a URI in some time, the program should send an e-mail notifying that the program in local computar may stopped. I Tried using sleep (), but it seems like each access is generated a new processing of the script and at the end of the sleep the scripts will run in parallel. I need to stop the previous processing and continue another! follow my code:

at each access, this function is called:

```
AtivarTimerDeAlerta($pm);
```

as functions that start the timer and call a callback that the mail is sent after the timer runs:

```
function AtivarTimerDeAlerta($pm, $tempo=TEMPO_TIMER)
{
   Timer($tempo,"EnviarEmailDeAlerta",array($pm));//reinicializa o timer.
}

function Timer($minutos=TEMPO_TIMER, $callback="", $params=array())
{
   sleep(60*$minutos);
   $p = count($params)>1 ? implode(",",$params) : count($params)==1 ? $params[0]:"";
   return $callback($p);
}
```

Could someone give me an idea how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: `touch('accesstime');` to create an empty file and/or set its last modification time to the current time. Then you can check `time()-filemtime('accesstime')` to find out how long ago it was touched.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think i could not explain clearly... a local program will access a server program made in PHP. I need to restart the php script execution each access of the local program... the main idea is restart the script before the timer ends!

Comment: is it possible using proc_open and proc_close ???

Comment: or maybe using opcache functions!!! I've never used this before. someone knows if it works?

Comment: I'v changed my aproach... I'll record the access in a log file and verify the last modifyed date to execute the action in the time I need. Anyway, if someone have an idea about how to do that in another way I'm going on following this post. thank you very much..